# Best approach to show / hide dialogs

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I have encountered a theoretical question. I'm using pyqt5, but this is probably are very generalistic and framework independent question.
I have a `QMainwindow` sitting around waiting for the user to do stuff. The user can **show / hide** dialogues (subclasses of `QDockwidgets`) as he chooses using the `QMenu` and the associated shortcuts (it's a checkable `QAction` for each individual dialogue).
I have been struggling with showing / hiding the dialogues efficiently. Currently, I'm just initiating them all at start up, hiding those that I don't want to show up in the beginning. This makes triggering the dialogues easy, since I can just `dialogue.show()` /`dialogue.hide()` depending on the dialogues current visibility. 
But I cannot believe that this is best practice and very efficient.

I have tried (**I currently do not have my pyqt environment set up on this computer, so I had to strip down my actual code without being able to test if this runs**):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class InfoPanel(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title='Tool Box'):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self, title)
        self.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable)
        self.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

        frame = QFrame()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView()
        self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(40, 40, 40)))
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(frame)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.showpanelAct = QAction("&Show Panel", self, enabled=True,checkable=True, shortcut="F10")
        self.showpanelAct.triggered.connect(lambda: self.showPanel(0))
        self.viewMenu = QMenu("&View", self)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.showpanelAct)
        self.setDockOptions(QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)

    def showPanel(self,i:int = 0): # this is not so smart - should construct and deconstuct to save memory!?
        if i == 0: #infopanel
            dialogueExists = True
            try: self.infoPanel
            #except NameError: #does not catch the error
            except:
                dialogueExists = False
            if dialogueExists:
                print('destroy')
                self.infoPanel.destroy()
            else:
                print('create')
                self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
                self.infoPanel.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Which works the first time, but after that, it only seems to trigger the destruction of the dialogue (which, surprisingly, does not crash anything it just keeps on going).
Why is that and is there a standard way to approach the showing hiding of dialogues?

Comment: IMHO, it's usual to setup any GUI stuff (like e.g. dialogs) at program start, show/hide it as needed by user's interaction, and destroy it at program end. I cannot imagine that GUI objects consume that much memory that it's worth to create/destroy them on demand. (View data is the exception e.g. model data for big tables. I usually discard such data when resp. parts of GUI become hidden due to closing a dialog.) This is how I do it in Qt. I did this as well before in gtkmm, and as well before in OSF/Motif. (I cannot remember how I did it when I started in GDI of Win3.1, probably wrong.) ;-)

Comment: For _a standard way_, you may consult the numerous examples in Qt doc. They probably illustrate how they (the Qt developers) think it should be used.

Comment: @Scheff Ok, so in my case I could do that with most dialogues and hide the creation / hiding of the dialogues at program start with the splash screen. I do have some dialogues that use mvc, for which I will probably destroy the **data** when closing it to save on memory.    I would still love to know why the `try: ... except: ...` approach doesn't work as I expected!?

Comment: Saving the memory is only the half of the intention. I don't know how you couple the data with model and view. I'm a big fan of signal driven things. I.e. I often have signals in my data which notify about changes. UI classes just connect to these signals and update them-selves automatically. This is especially maintenance-friendly concerning multiple (different) views onto the same data. However, Qt updates are in certain cases expensive (i.e. terrible slow) especially concerning MVC widgets. Hence, I try to limit the updates to the absolute necessary amount (by clearing models of hidden UI).

Comment: Concerning the `try: ... except: ...`: Could you extend your sample to a [MCVE]?

Comment: @Scheff: Yes, after prototyping in Tkinter I have now switched to PyQt5 and have adopted a very strict signal structure similar to what you've suggested. But **clearing** the model seem like a good approach, Thanks!

Comment: @Scheff: Just edited my question, hope this is working since I am currently not on the computer that runs pyqt5.

Comment: @Scheff - I do not agree. There is absolutely no reason to setup the GUI stuff at start up. Each GUI element can have different lifetime, some can be generated dynamically with a content based on some events. Then there is also the performance penalty. If you want your applications to work efficiently (I do!), you must hate the idea to create stuff which you may not need. Modal dialogs (opened with dlg.exec(); ) can be created on the stack (in C++) and they are destroyed at the end of the scope. Etc. In my view, this is a lazy-programmer-approach...

Comment: @V.K. I started with _IMHO, it's usual ..._ Alternatively, dialogs may be created on demand and then live (visible or not) until end of application. Alternatively, instances (preferable modal dialogs with short appearance time) may be created on stack. Additonally, there are these static functions (e.g. to open native dialogs). Qt examples seem to prefer to create everything with `new`, even members of classes in composed widgets what I don't understand. It works fine as well if child widgets are simply members of that class. TLDR, OP asked for best practice. Do you see any?

Comment: @V.K. _Etc. In my view, this is a lazy-programmer-approach..._ Yepp. Lazy programming -> maintenance friendly -> less effort -> less devel. costs -> shorter time to market. Lazy developers are good for business. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff - Constructing everything at startup is definitely not the best practice. It might be a lazy-programmer's quick-and-dirty way, but it is not the best way to produce a high quality software. The best way is to know your stuff and know the needed lifetime of your GUI elements and manage it accordingly. Create and display the stuff just when you need it and delete it just after you stop needing it. And if you do not want to delete your closed dialogs manually, you can set the attribute `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` ... It is so easy with Qt.

Comment: @Scheff - Lazy programmers are totally disastrous for the business, they are lazy to think!

Comment: @V.K. Saving memory can also mean fragmenting it. Keeping free memory on a PC which doesn't need to run anything else is a waste. Over optimizing applications for no practical reason is a waste of development time which is much more expensive then the few saved bytes/microseconds of faster run-time are worth. I believe it's not that easy as you describe it.

Comment: @Scheff - Btw. static things which you can generate at startup is typical for simple applications. In larger application, there are too many dynamic content that I cannot imagine generating everything at startup. Fragmenting memory is definitely not an issue in GUI related applications. Deleting stuff which you do not need is definitely not over-optimization. Proper design of program structure and lifetimes is the core design and architectural decision, not some over-optimization of implementation details.

Comment: @Scheff - I hate maintaining software created by lazy programmers! They do not think ahead, they just quickly type something which they do not understand... and they are proud of themselves how productive they are. Wrong!

Comment: @Scheff - It is just coincidence that at work I have just similar issue. Lazy programmers thought they create stuff at startup, hide it, fill content, show it, hide it, clear old content, fill new content, show it again, hide it, clear the content etc. Should I describe in details how big maintenance burden this is? This is really messy code and is full of bugs. Create-show-delete-create-show-delete would be much much simpler than create-show-hide-reset-prepare-show-hide-reset-prepare-show-hide-die. Btw. new requirement now is to have two instances of this GUI element instead of one. Poor me.

Comment: Alright... Just to add some points from a lazy biologist who happens to code point of view:
I am currently rewriting an application [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itagbiology/) I prototyped in python tkinter and will switch to PyQT. I will use multiple docks, some of which I know will be there from the beginning (toolboxes, an overview window etc.). I will init those dialogues at start up and .show() .hide() them on demand. The remaining dialogues will be **initialised** on demand. I think there is no "best solution", that's why I was asking about "best practice".

Comment: The overview dock, for example, shows a smaller version of the image in the mainwindow. Creating this window on demand is slow, since it would mean reloading and rescaling the main window image every time. Therefore, it makes more sense to me to follow @Scheff comment. In another case, I will have a generalised properties dock (basically a dock holding a model view for whatever data I want to look at). This is a simple, fast process and the dock will be destroyed and initialised on demand, as it doesn't take time to fill the widget, following V.K. suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break from coding the solution to my problem was very obvious. Going back to my original code (which did not produce the expected output of creating / destroying the dialogue `self.infoPanel` on demand):

```
dialogueExists = True
try: self.infoPanel
#except NameError: #does not catch the error
except:
  dialogueExists = False
if dialogueExists:
  print('destroy')
  self.infoPanel.destroy()
else:
  print('create')
  self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
  self.infoPanel.show()
```

My main problem was that I confused two separate things. Qt destroyed the widget contained in the object `self.infoPanel` when I called `self.infoPanel.destroy()`. But that doesn't mean the object self.infoPanel does not exist (that's exactly what I use `try: ...` for, to see if the object exists). The simple and obvious way to create and destroy dialogues on demand obviously involves **deleting the object from the environment** (`del self.infoPanel`).
The working code is:

```
dialogueExists = True
try:
  self.infoPanel.destroy() #not sure this is needed, but I guess it doesn't hurt
  del self.infoPanel #this is the deletion of the actual object
except:
  dialogueExists = False
if not dialogueExists : 
  self.infoPanel = InfoPanel()
```

Cheers and many thanks for the helpful advice on deciding whether to show / hide dialogues or to create / destroy them!

Answer (score 0):

I took the exposed [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of OP and tried to make it running in my [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10.

At first I had to apply little fixes. (OP stated that he was not able to test it at the time of publishing.)

First, I inserted a “hut” at first line for convenient start in `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Second, the `self.viewMenu` didn't appear. Hence, I inserted a line after

```
        self.viewMenu = QMenu("&View", self)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.showpanelAct)
```

to add the `viewMenu` to main menu bar:

```
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.viewMenu)
```

which fixed it.

Third, when clicking the menu item I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testQDockPanelShowHide.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    self.showpanelAct.triggered.connect(lambda: self.showPanel(0))
  File "./testQDockPanelShowHide.py", line 45, in showPanel
    self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
  File "./testQDockPanelShowHide.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(40, 40, 40)))
NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I must admit that my Python knowledge is very limited. (I'm the guy who writes the Python bindings in C++ for the colleagues. So, my colleagues are the actual experts. At most, I play a little bit in Python when I test whether new implemented bindings do what's expected.) However, I modified

```
    self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(40, 40, 40)))
```

to:

```
    self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(40, 40, 40)))
```

which fixed this issue.

After this, I got the behavior described by OP and did a closer look where I (and OP) suspected the error:

```
    def showPanel(self,i:int = 0): # this is not so smart - should construct and deconstuct to save memory!?
        if i == 0: #infopanel
            dialogueExists = True
            try: self.infoPanel
            #except NameError: #does not catch the error
            except:
                dialogueExists = False
            if dialogueExists:
                print('destroy')
                self.infoPanel.destroy()
            else:
                print('create')
                self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
                self.infoPanel.show()
```

I strongly believe that `try: self.infoPanel` doesn't do what OP thinks it would.

It tries to access `self.infoPanel` which isn't existing until the first call of this method. (Please, be aware, *the member variable* `self.infoPanel` isn't existing.) So, the `except:` branch is executed and sets `dialogueExists = False` which a few lines later causes `self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init`. Now, the member variable `self.infoPanel` is existing, and the `try: self.infoPanel` will never fail again until destruction of this `MainWindow`.

Out of curiosity, I had a look at [`QWidget.destroy()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#destroy) (to be sure not to tell something wrong):

> #### QWidget.destroy (self, bool destroyWindow = True, bool destroySubWindows = True)
>
> Frees up window system resources. Destroys the widget window if destroyWindow is true.
>
> destroy() calls itself recursively for all the child widgets, passing destroySubWindows for the destroyWindow parameter. To have more control over destruction of subwidgets, destroy subwidgets selectively first.
>
> This function is usually called from the QWidget destructor.

It definitely doesn't destroy the member variable `self.infoPanel`.

After having understood this, a fix was easy and obvious:

```
    def showPanel(self,i:int = 0): # this is not so smart - should construct and deconstuct to save memory!?
        if i == 0: #infopanel
            try: self.infoPanel
            #except NameError: #does not catch the error
            except:
                print('create')
                self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
            if self.infoPanel.isVisible():
                self.infoPanel.hide()
            else:
                self.infoPanel.show()
```

Btw. I replaced `destroy()` by `hide()` which makes a re-creation of the `InfoPanel()` obsolete.

I tested this by toggling the menu item multiple times – it works as expected now (at least, it looks like).

The complete sample finally:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class InfoPanel(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title='Tool Box'):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self, title)
        self.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable)
        self.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

        frame = QFrame()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.canvas = QGraphicsView()
#        self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(40, 40, 40)))
        self.canvas.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(40, 40, 40)))
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(frame)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.showpanelAct = QAction("&Show Panel", self, enabled=True,checkable=True, shortcut="F10")
        self.showpanelAct.triggered.connect(lambda: self.showPanel(0))
        self.viewMenu = QMenu("&View", self)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.showpanelAct)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.viewMenu)
        self.setDockOptions(QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)

    def showPanel(self,i:int = 0): # this is not so smart - should construct and deconstuct to save memory!?
        if i == 0: #infopanel
            try: self.infoPanel
            #except NameError: #does not catch the error
            except:
                print('create')
                self.infoPanel = InfoPanel() #init
            if self.infoPanel.isVisible():
                self.infoPanel.hide()
            else:
                self.infoPanel.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: Snapshot of MCVE]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check this when I get home!